# function to find duplicate data in cells after a @ symbol

Tags: microsoft-excel, email

I have two columns on excel with 2000 emails addresses in each column. These columns will multiple email address for a certain company but to different people.  I am trying to match the data in these columns showing all the matching emails for each company. I guess the function would need to search the column for matching data after the @ symbol but I don't know how to write it

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1809897/edit) your question and add sample of your data and expected results.

Comment: If this is a one-off, simply split the column(s) containing mail addresses using the Data/Text-to-columns command. Then make a pivottable, using the new column as row header.

Answer (score 0):

Use the LEFT and FIND functions to extract the domain name from each email address. For example, if your email addresses are in column A, you can use the formula `=LEFT(A1,FIND("@",C1)-1)` in cell B1 and drag it down to the end of your data.